# Prove the set of sequences $c_0$ which converge to zero in $l_{\infty}$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Prove the set of sequences which converge to zero in $l_{\infty}$ is closed.

Let $x_n(k)\rightarrow x(k)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  With $x_n(k)\in c_0$ and $x(k)\in l_{\infty}$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Then there exists an $N>0$ such that 
$$\parallel x_N-x\parallel_{\infty}:=\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x_N(k)-x(k)|\leq\varepsilon.$$

Then we have,
\begin{align}
|x(k)| &= |x(k) - x_N(k) + x_N(k)| \\\\
&\leq |x_N(k) - x(k)| + |x_N(k)| \\\\
&\leq \varepsilon + |x_N(k)|\rightarrow \varepsilon\;\; \text{as}\;\; k\rightarrow\infty. 
\end{align}

Therefore since $\varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily we can conclude that $x(k)\rightarrow0$ and thus that $x(k)\in c_0$

Can someone check my work on this?  It seems too slick and painless to be correct.

Comment: BTW this post is about the same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146713/subset-of-sequence-space-closed This one is about convergent sequences: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557017/closed-subspace-of-l-infty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One more proof: $f:\ell_\infty \to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \lim\sup |x_n|$ is continuous so that $c_0= f^{-1}(\lbrace 0\rbrace)$ is closed.

Comment: how we can show the continuity part?

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \|x-y\|_\infty$.

Comment: @Jochen , why this inequality holds...

Comment: @Beginner Because the l inf norm is defined to be the supremum of the entire series, i.e the greatest difference two points of the sequence can have.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is correct. Just to beef up this post, I'll sketch a  slightly different proof:  the complement of $l_0$ is open.

If $x\notin l_0$,  let $r=\frac12\limsup_{k\to\infty} |x(k)|$. If $\|x-y\|\le r$, then $$\limsup|y(k)| \ge \limsup_{k\to\infty} |x(k)|-r =r$$ hence $y\notin l_0$.

By the way, this is the first time I see notation $l_0$ used for this subspace; all sources I know use $c_0$. I think $l_0$ is [prone to confusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_p_.3D_0).